# Azure Mysql Database service generate failed connections when too many connections needed

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database

We have a problem when applying stress test (sending too many users in the same time) to our application, our application trying to create new connections to serve users, but azure Mysql DB service is generating a lot of failed connections.

[image: Azure Failed connections diagram]

even the CPU usage of DB server is as the Azure diagram is less than 10 percent.

[image: Azure Mysql DB CPU usage]

I'm thinking that the problem is because the default server parameters is not optimal here are some of these parameters

[image: Azure Server Parameter]

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on the number of connections per pricing tier. For instance, a Basic tier with 1 vCore allows a maximum of 50 connections, while a Basic tier with 2 vCore allows a maximum of 100 connections. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-server-parameters#max_connections) documentation for more details.

[image]

Comment: we have a 32 vCore which means we should have 5000 connections, but it served about 100 connections and generate about 2500 failed connections

Comment: The .NET MySQL data provider supports advanced connection pooling. Are you using it? https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/ComparingProviders.html

Comment: no actually the problem was in our application, we used "pdo persistent connection" and it worked i don't know if it has some disadvantage but it solved the problem.

Comment: Please consider to add your solution as an answer.